# Weird double summation indexing

Tags: summation, notation

I was reading this paper where I came across a function with a weird double summation notation. The function roughly looks like this,

$$2\sum_{x = 1}^{11}(30-x)\sum_{t = 1}^{x-1} t^2$$

My question is, what will be the value of inner summation when $x = 1$? My best guess was, when $x = 1$, $x-1$  is not defined in the series. Thus the answer will be $0$ when $x = 1$.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If $x=1$ in the inner summation then there are no possible values of $t$ and therefore no terms in the sum.  An empty sum by convention evaluates to zero.

Comment: @David Thank you that helps!!

Comment: At $t=0$, $t^2=0$.

Comment: I don't think that it is 0, I think it is just wrong and not defined!

Comment: @Chessplayer: It's notation; it means whatever most people say it means, just like $\pi$ or $+$ or $\infty$. I suspect the convention that the empty sum equals zero is nearly universal. I would probably start $x$ at $2$ instead, to keep things clear, but in my opinion starting $x$ at $1$ doesn't make the expression wrong or even unclear.

Comment: it doesn't sound right. For example, when you do derivative part by part, there is a whole explanation for why you need to start your sum from $n=1$ and not $n=0$ now, and not just because it means $0$. Do you get my point?

Comment: @Chessplayer: Not really, I'm afraid. Do you mean a Riemann summation for the integral? The derivative is a limit of a ratio in standard analysis. ¶ Anyway, my point stands. It's a shame that it doesn't sound right to you, because that convention is as good as cast in stone.

Comment: @BrianTung No! I mean that by some conditions, $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n)^{'}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_nx^n)^{'}$

Comment: @Chessplayer: That seems like a different thing: They differ only by the derivative of $a_0$, a constant, but the derivative vanishes for constants.